# Change of device orientation when notification is present corrupts UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, orientation

I subscribed to push notifications from Apple in my iPad app. When any notification is present on screen, if I change the orientation of my device, then my UI is corrupted. Is there any way where in I can handle this issue ?

I implement from UIView and not from UIViewController. I already subscribed to change of device notification. My UI is properly displayed in all the cases except when there is notification present.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot do that

Comment: Oh - rep limit? Upload it to an image sharing service and share link here.